# Pushing array contents to DataFrame - Julia

Tags: arrays, dataframe, julia

I have an array X that I would like to push onto a DataFrame at regular intervals. Suppose the array is of size 7. Currently, I am doing:

```
push!(df, (week, X[1], X[2], X[3], X[4], X[5], X[6], X[7], sum(X)))
```

Is there an easier way to output this array, like a loop of some sort? I'm sure it's a simple answer but I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation.

Comment: If your only goal is to concatenate values as a column, then you can use `vcat`: `vcat(week, X..., sum(X))`. And push this into `df`. The `...` is called the splatting operator, you can read more on it here: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/faq/

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question.  Could you clarify the dimensions of `X`?  Is it just a vector?  What about `df`?

Comment: @niczky12 - Your method is exactly what I needed! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi @BrandonEdwards added this as answer. Also, you don't need to use the `...` operator when using `vcat`, but it's still good to know about. Feel free to accept my answer or let me know if you have other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comment as answer.

It seems like what you want to achieve here is to create new vector as a combination of vectors and single values. You can achieve this by using the `vcat()` function which combines your objects vertically into as single array.

Instead of:

```
(week, X[1], X[2], X[3], X[4], X[5], X[6], X[7], sum(X))
```

You can create the same object as such:

```
vcat(week, X, sum(X))
```

And then `push!()` this to your original dataframe as before.